# how to proceed after clicking a link to new page in selenium in python

Tags: selenium, python

I am clicking a link which takes me to new page, but I don't know how to proceed after that. When I try to find an element by id in the next page it gives me error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"myid"}
```

My code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('myurl')
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('closeMessageButton') # Find the search box
elem.click() # this takes me to new link

# now I am searching id from new page
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('newpage_id')  #
elem.click()
```

I have seen this http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html but couldn't succeed in implementing for my case.
I think the information in browser is not updated yet.

Comment: page? As in new browser tab or new window? You would need to switch to new window or tab to recognize that new element.

Comment: Also you would need to implement some kind of wait, so that the script waits for some time, before jumping into new page and then finding element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you don't switch to opened window, and webdriver searches for elements in the old page instead of the newly opened one.

Solution:

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
```

This java method's part switches to the newest window. Also consider maximizing it, because sometimes tests masses up in not maximized windows.
Another point: waiting. Try to read here about different types of [wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858972/how-can-i-ask-the-selenium-webdriver-to-wait-for-few-seconds-in-java). Good luck.

Comment: thank you ,this is useful for me
may i know how to write this sample code

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Python. This code will switch to the second window in your browser.

```
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
```

Comment: It is important to note that the new handle will not be available until after then new page starts to open - hence you may need a Wait.

Answer (score 0):

After navigating to the new page if you want to do something on that new page

newURl = driver.window_handles[0]

driver.switch_to.window(newURl)

After doing this you can do something in the new url without getting "no such element exceptions"